# How do I build a dynamic route in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I would like to construct a URL of the form

```
/my_objects/city_code
```

and I would like it to link to my controller, my_objects_controller.rb, specifically this method

```
  def search_by_code
     ...
  end
```

Then in this method, I would like to be able to extract "city_code" as a variable.  I don't know routes well enough to figure out how to do this.  How can I pull this off?

**Edit:** I tried adding your route to the existing block I already had ...

```
  resources :my_objects do
    collection do
      post 'create'
      get 'import'
      get '/index', to: redirect('/races/index')
      get 'search'
      get 'stats'
      get ':code', to: '#search_by_code'
    end
  end
```

but it resulted in the below error when I started my app ...

```
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:314:in `block (2 levels) in check_controller_and_action': '' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have in your *config/routes.rb*:

```
get '/my_objects/:code', to: 'my_objects#show'
```

Then in your *my_objects_controller.rb* in the *show action* pass the *params[:code]* to the model:

```
MyObject.search_by_code(params[:code])
```

In the *my_object.rb* model:

```
def self.search_by_code(code)
  MyObject.where(code: code)
end
```

**FIX ACCORDING TO QUESTION EDIT:**

*Fixed routes.rb:*

```
resources :my_objects do
    collection do
      post 'create'
      get 'import'
      get '/index', to: redirect('/races/index')
      get 'search'
      get 'stats'
      get ':code', to: 'my_objects#search_by_code'
    end
  end
```

Run this from your terminal:

```
rake routes
```

and it will output:

```
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
       my_objects POST   /my_objects/create(.:format)   my_objects#create
import_my_objects GET    /my_objects/import(.:format)   my_objects#import
 index_my_objects GET    /my_objects/index(.:format)    redirect(301, /races/index)
search_my_objects GET    /my_objects/search(.:format)   my_objects#search
 stats_my_objects GET    /my_objects/stats(.:format)    my_objects#stats
                  GET    /my_objects/:code(.:format)    my_objects#search_by_code
                  GET    /my_objects(.:format)          my_objects#index
                  POST   /my_objects(.:format)          my_objects#create
    new_my_object GET    /my_objects/new(.:format)      my_objects#new
   edit_my_object GET    /my_objects/:id/edit(.:format) my_objects#edit
        my_object GET    /my_objects/:id(.:format)      my_objects#show
                  PATCH  /my_objects/:id(.:format)      my_objects#update
                  PUT    /my_objects/:id(.:format)      my_objects#update
                  DELETE /my_objects/:id(.:format)      my_objects#destroy
```

As you can see you have two same paths:

```
GET    /my_objects/:code(.:format)
```

and

```
GET    /my_objects/:id(.:format)
```

This might cause a **problem**. If not a problem it is kind of duplicate and bad small code.

Comment: I already had a resources block for my_objects so I tried to add a modified version of your code, "get ':code', to: '#search_by_code'" but I got an error.  Please see my edit . I may not have applied your logic properly.

Comment: @Dave This is the correct way. Pls fix your code and let me know.
      get ':code', to: 'my_objects#search_by_code'

Comment: You're saying I should remove all my lines from the "collections do" method and put them as individual lines int he file -- e.g. split out "post 'create'" from the "collections do" block?

Comment: @Dave Please check my answer edit. If it is more clear try to improve your code and let me know, if it works better.